# Webaii - Unable to locate an element in a Silver Light Web page

Tags: c#, telerik, automation, webaii

Hi I am trying to locate an element on a silver light web page but I am struggling to find the element. Below is the XAML. The element looks like it would be a 'TextBlock' element, but I wrote some C# code that put all the TextBlock elements on the web page into a collection variable, and then  checked through each of the TextBlock elements and it definitely was not one of them. Does anybody know what the data type of the element code be from looking at the XAML below? Or know a way of finding this element?

`<ulib:Header Grid.Row="0"
                         IsEditable="True"
                         Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay}"
                         Margin="3"
                         Watermark="Enter grid name here..."/>
UltraAS.Library.Controls.Header:
public class Header : System.Windows.Controls.UserControl
public class UserControl : System.Windows.Controls.Control`

Comment: This is your third question about this particular product, which has a Customer support for licensed versions from a particular company (owner). Did you try to contact them?